# cordova-plugin-geofence error on ios ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have installed **cordova-plugin-geofence** in my project but when i try to build it gives following errors :-

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/OnTheList/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/GeofencePlugin.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/OnTheList/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/SwiftData.swift
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/OnTheList/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/SwiftyJson.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(4 failures)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,OnTheList.xcworkspace,-scheme,OnTheList,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,OnTheList.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/itr/Desktop/richboy/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

How to resolve these errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution work for me

Go to your `project->platforms->ios->projectName(folder)->plugins->cordova-plugin-geofence`

You will find four files.
Replace this file with this file content https://github.com/ypelud/cordova-plugin-geofence/tree/d2e1f22340ac2cd07559598fd290df462e75055d/src/ios